# Group dates withing the same hour range

Tags: c#

Let's say I have the following dates:

```
"2017-11-06 15:29", 
"2017-11-06 15:30", 
"2017-11-06 15:51", 
"2017-11-06 16:30", 
"2017-11-06 16:31"
```

I would like to group them in 60 minute chunks, relative from the first item:

```
0: ["2017-11-06 15:29", "2017-11-06 15:30", "2017-11-06 15:51"]
1: ["2017-11-06 16:30", "2017-11-06 16:31"]
```

I tried `dates.GroupWhile((previous, current) => previous.AddMinutes(60) >= current)` from [Grouping Contiguous Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413961/grouping-contiguous-dates), but they all end up in the same group.

Comment: So, if there was another record with 16:28 it would be in the first group?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That method doesn't really do what you want, it's grouping based on last element. I think you want something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> continueSelector)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }

        var currentGroup = new List<T> { enumerator.Current };
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = enumerator.Current;

            if (continueSelector(currentGroup.First(), current))
            {
                currentGroup.Add(current);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return currentGroup;
                currentGroup = new List<T> { current };
            }
        }

        yield return currentGroup;
    }
}
```

This would be grouping based on first element of each new group making them relative to each other and giving you your expected result if you use it like this:

```
dates.GroupWhile((groupDate, current) => (current - groupDate).TotalSeconds < 3600)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need the first time, then you can use `TimeSpan.TotalHours` (cast the `double` to `int`):

```
DateTime firstDt = dates.Min(); 
var hourGroups = dates.GroupBy(dt => (int)(dt - firstDt).TotalHours);
```

Sample:

```
var dates = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15 * i)).ToList();
```

and result:

```
foreach (var dtGroup in hourGroups)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", dtGroup));
```

---

```
07.11.2017 10:17:47, 07.11.2017 10:32:47, 07.11.2017 10:47:47, 07.11.2017 11:02:47
07.11.2017 11:17:47, 07.11.2017 11:32:47, 07.11.2017 11:47:47, 07.11.2017 12:02:47
07.11.2017 12:17:47, 07.11.2017 12:32:47, 07.11.2017 12:47:47, 07.11.2017 13:02:47
07.11.2017 13:17:47, 07.11.2017 13:32:47, 07.11.2017 13:47:47, 07.11.2017 14:02:47
07.11.2017 14:17:47, 07.11.2017 14:32:47, 07.11.2017 14:47:47, 07.11.2017 15:02:47
07.11.2017 15:17:47, 07.11.2017 15:32:47, 07.11.2017 15:47:47, 07.11.2017 16:02:47
07.11.2017 16:17:47, 07.11.2017 16:32:47, 07.11.2017 16:47:47, 07.11.2017 17:02:47
07.11.2017 17:17:47, 07.11.2017 17:32:47
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly start by converting your strings into `DateTime`:

```
string[] strDates =
{
    "2017-11-06 15:29",
    "2017-11-06 15:30",
    "2017-11-06 15:51",
    "2017-11-06 16:30",
    "2017-11-06 16:31",
    "2017-11-06 16:28"
};

var dates = strDates.Select(date => DateTime.Parse(date))
    .OrderBy(date => date)  // Only needed if the original times might be unordered.
    .ToArray();
```

Then you can group the dates by hour from the first time like so:

```
var startTicks = dates[0].Ticks;

var grouped = dates.GroupBy(date => (date.Ticks - startTicks)/TimeSpan.TicksPerHour);
```

This works by grouping the times using their tick counts divided by the number ticks per hour - which has the effect of grouping them all by hours (but relative to the first time in the list).

My test code printed them out thusly:

```
foreach (var group in grouped)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", group));
```

Giving the following output:

```
06/11/2017 15:29:00, 06/11/2017 15:30:00, 06/11/2017 15:51:00, 06/11/2017 16:28:00
06/11/2017 16:30:00, 06/11/2017 16:31:00
```

Comment: You'd have to subtract the first items number of minutes from all dates and then group them by hour and put it all back.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to group simply by the hour, check the comments above

Comment: Fixed by using `TickCount` and `TicksPerHour`.